# gulp execute task with callback in command line

Tags: gulp

I am using gulp **v4**.

gulpfile.js:

```
function mysass() {
    return gulp.src([css.sasspth + '/site.scss'])
      .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(css.assets));
  }

exports.mysass = mysass;
```

The above working but I want to do something different.
What I am trying to do is to pass a callback to gulp.src like this.

```
function mysass(filepath) {
    return gulp.src(filepath)
   .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
   .pipe(gulp.dest(css.assets));
}

exports.mysass = mysass;
```

When I run this in command line I get an error.

```
gulp mysass(css.sasspth + '/site.scss')
```

The error:

```
Task never defined: mysass(css.sasspth
```

How to make this to work?

Answer (score 1):

There is no possibility to directly invoke Gulp tasks with parameters in the same way as you would call a function in Javascript. You can extract parameters from the command line in the same way as in any NodeJS application (e.g. [`minimist`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimist), [`yargs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs), [`Commander.js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander)), but you need to programmatically access them by yourself:

```
const argv = require('yargs').argv

function mysass() {
    return gulp.src(argv.path)
        .pipe(...)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(...))
}
```

As you try to access the variable `css.sasspath` in your argument, you would need to invoke [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) or something similar, but as always, take care when doing so.